# Change CSS attribute value with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the value of top attribute of this CSS using Jquery but I'm not able to get a hold of it. I have tried the following approaches but they're having no effect. What am I doing wrong?

**CSS:**

```
body.menu-is-horizontal:not(.sidebar-hidden) #navigation {
    width:75%;
    top: 93px !important;
}
```

My attempts:

```
$("body.menu-is-horizontal:not(.sidebar-hidden) #navigation").css("top", "67px !important");

$("#navigation.body.menu-is-horizontal:not(.sidebar-hidden)").css("top", "67px !important");

$("#navigation .body.menu-is-horizontal:not(.sidebar-hidden)").css("top", "67px !important");
```

Comment: Use `$('#navigation').style('top', '67px', '!important');`

Comment: Please see the answers on the linked question. Let me know if that works.

Comment: `$('#navigation').style('top', '67px', '!important'); ` worked. Thanks